# Is it possible to use two versions of HTML in a single document

Tags: html

It can be kinda weird but is this possible to use HTML version 4 and HTML version 5 on the same document. Why I ask this question because both versions ignore some specific tag function. Forex: Previous HTML version  may not support canvas or graphical element and few tags like applet are ignored by HTML 5 then how someone can use both tags. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to write a *valid* document that conforms to the specification if you mix versions of HTML.

Browsers are pretty good at error recovery though.

That said, support for `<applet>` is dying and you may find plenty of people unable to run the Java.